# How to fetch content of XML root element in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    First line. <br/> Second line.
</root>
```

As an output I want to get: `'\nFirst line. <br/> Second line.\n'`
I just want to notice, if the root element contains other nested elements, they should be returned as is.

Comment: So you just want to strip off the start and end tags of the root element?

Comment: Basically, yes. But I need general-purpose approach. I mean that XML could be not exactly the same, e.g. it can contain <!DOCTYPE> declaration, etc.

Comment: Do you want the parsed content of the root element (which might include expanded entities for example), or do you simply want the verbatim string between the start and end tags?

Answer (score 3):

The first that I came up with:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, tostring

source = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    First line.<br/>Second line.
</root>
'''

xml = fromstring(source)
result = tostring(xml).lstrip('<%s>' % xml.tag).rstrip('</%s>' % xml.tag)

print result

# output:
#
#   First line.<br/>Second line. 
#
```

But it's not truly general-purpose approach since it fails if opening root element (`<root>`) contains any attribute.

**UPDATE:** This approach has another issue. Since `lstrip` and `rstrip` match any combination of given chars, you can face such problem:

```
# input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><p>First line</p></root>

# result:
p>First line</p
```

If your really need only literal string between the opening and closing tags (as you mentioned in the comment), you can use this:

```
from string import index, rindex
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, tostring

source = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root attr1="val1">
    First line.<br/>Second line.
</root>
'''

# following two lines are needed just to cut
# declaration, doctypes, etc.
xml = fromstring(source)
xml_str = tostring(xml)

start = index(xml_str, '>')
end = rindex(xml_str, '<')

result = xml_str[start + 1 : -(len(xml_str) - end)]
```

Not the most elegant approach, but unlike the previous one it works correctly with attributes within opening tag as well as with any valid xml document.

Comment: `xml_str = tostring()` should be `xml_str = tostring(xml)`.

Comment: Namespaces can mess things up. For example, if the root element has a `xmlns="http://foo.com"` declaration, your solution does not quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Parse from file:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
tree = parse('yourxmlfile.xml')
print tree.getroot().text
```

Parse from string:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
print fromstring(yourxmlstr).text
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I parse XML from string, not from file?

Comment: That would return `'\n    First line. '`, not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @asm from string: use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring).

Comment: @Santa Unfortunately `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring` returns `Element`, not `ElementTree`. So it doesn't contain `getroot()` method.

Comment: @Santa You are right. But unfortunately you are also right with your first comment :). `text` attribute returns only `\n First line. `