# Set XML root with libxml2 Python bindings

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML

```
<Head>
<child></child>
</Head>
```

And I want to alter the XML to something like this:

```
<Parent>
<child></child>
</Parent>
```

How do I do this? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465455/how-to-read-root-xml-tag-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669420/how-to-fetch-content-of-xml-root-element-in-python) but they use Element tree.

Comment: What is lxml2? Do you mean [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or perhaps the [libxml2 Python bindings](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html)?

Comment: I am sorry, updated the question tag.

Comment: If my answer solves this problem, don't forget to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, you have this original file.

```
<Head>
<child>this is text for child</child>
</Head>
```

Then you can use `xml.dom.minidom` to change name of root tag.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python


import xml.dom.minidom

info = '''
<Head>
<child>this is text for child</child>
</Head>
'''

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(info)
dom.firstChild.tagName = 'parent'
# save it to any file you want
xml_file = 'C:\\temp\\lch.xml'
f = open(xml_file, 'wb')
dom.writexml(f)
f.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><parent>
<child>this is text for child</child>
</parent>
```